# dependent vs depended vs depending

Tags: adjectives, gerunds

> 1. Low rainfall isn´t **depended** on heat.
> 2. Low rainfall isn´t **dependent** on heat.
> 3. Low rainfall isn´t **depending** on heat.

P.S. This is from my exam. And there´re many doubts about the question. Personally I think that #1 and #2 (***depended*** and ***dependent***) are suitable. But I´m not sure.

Comment: Personally I think that although *dependent* is the only syntactically valid form here, it's not a very suitable word for what I assume is the intended meaning *(Low rainfall **isn´t always caused by / correlated with** heat)*. Also note that *there´re many doubts* is an extremely non-standard written contraction.

Comment: Thanks! The beginning of a paragraph look like ´The geological definition of a desert is a place that receives less than ten inches of rain each year. Low rainfall isn´t depend* on heat, though´. Your meaning isn´t accurate. Is ´there´s´ ok to write or only 'there is'?

Comment: In my opinion the construction *X is dependent on Y* nearly always implies that X (or some observer) "wants" X to exist. So given that "low rainfall" is almost never a "desirable" condition, it's not a very good choice of word to describe the relationship/correlation. The same would apply to, say, *Death is dependent on the permanent cessation of brain activity*. In principle you might *almost* be able to say that to a trainee doctor when you're teaching him the principles of diagnosing "death", but in practice that's just not how we talk. Just as we don't write *there´re many doubts.*

Comment: That was in the task. Perhaps task creators think it´s correct. Anyway  what about other words(depended)? With whole context, does your opinion remain the same?

Comment: Trevor, thanks! I haven´t noticed this website before. I´ll go there.

Answer (score 2):

The correct word for the sentence in question is *dependent*.

> Low rainfall isn´t **dependent** on heat.
>   
>  
>   (Low rainfall is neither caused by nor prevented by the amount of heat.)
>   
>   **dependent** – adjective   (predicative)   (dependent on/upon)
>   
>    
>   **1**   Contingent on or determined by.
>   
>  
>   – [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dependent)

The same sentence cannot be rephrased to make sense with
the other word choices, *depended* or *depending*,
and still sound natural.
Instead, here are related sentences with those other variations.

> Rainfall level has never **depended** on heat.
>   
>  
>   Rainfall may be low, **depending** on heat.

In the test sentence, *depended* was probably given as a misleading choice
only because of its similarity, when spoken, to “dependent.”
A different sense of *depending*, however may be used naturally
in a completely different sentence
that structurally resembles the test sentence.

> I am not **depending** on free advice.
>   
>  
>   (I am not relying on, nor even asking for, free advice.)
>   
>   **depend** – verb   (depend on/upon)
>   
>    
>   **2**   Rely on:   
>         ‘the kind of person you could depend on’
>   
>  
>   – [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/depend#depend__8)