# Depending or dependent?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, verbs, adjectives

"Sometimes the tiles were cold, other times warm, dependent on when I woke up."
or
"Sometimes the tiles were cold, other times warm, depending on when I woke up."

If both are correct, which is better? If both are incorrect, is there an alternative?

Comment: see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93147/dependent-vs-depended-vs-depending

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dependent vs depended vs depending](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93147/dependent-vs-depended-vs-depending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "depending" form seems better.

We use "dependent" in expressions like "The temperature was dependent on the time I woke up." But in your example a participle phrase is better.